# How detect which delete button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

im using Semantic-UI for my web. I have table with data, on each row is delete button. When button is clicked, modal is shown. Modal have two buttons, cancel or confirm. When i click confirm i want to delete row from DB. But how i detect which button was clicked?

Table in HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>      
      <button id='1' class="delete button"></button>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Name2</td>
   <td>      
      <button id='2' class="delete button"></button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

When i click on delete button in table, javascript modal is shown. MODAL Javascript

```
$('#removeAcredicationModal')
                .modal({
                    transition       : 'vertical flip',
                    mobileTransition : 'horizontal flip',
                    closable         : false,
                    approve          : '.submit, .approve',
                    deny             : '.cancel'
                    }
                })
                .modal('attach events', '.delete', 'show')
            ;
```

Modal HTML

```
<div id="removeAcredicationModal" class="ui small modal">
   <div class="ui approve submit green labeled icon button">
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
      Delete
   </div>
   <div class="ui cancel red labeled icon button">
      <i class="remove icon"></i>
      Cancel
   </div>
</div>
```

On confirm button click i want to delete item from DB

```
function doDelete(){
    var idOfRowToDelete = "??";
    //How to get the ID placed in table?
    //Using controller, etc...
};
```

Any ideas how to get ID from table in toDelete function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.target.id`

```
$('button').click(function(e)
{
    alert(e.target.id);
   e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/38h1ub4j/